# How to get ThreadStatic value of another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is it possible given the `Thread` reference to get `ThreadStatic` value for that thread?

Comment: `[ThreadStatic]` data is local to a thread precisely to prevent issues with multiple threads accessing a value. Allowing cross-thread access would defeat the purpose. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I want threads to store their current state in ThreadStatic field and logger to periodically dump worker's thread states.

Comment: I can smell the [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to access another thread's data then why it is `[ThreadStatic]` in first place ?

Comment: @Poma, then make it more object-oriented, let your threads register in logger and pass its state (periodically?). "Tell, don't ask" rule here.

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding this the wrong way, but if you want a logger to display the status of a group of threads, why not keep them in a List<Thread> and check the State property of each thread? I've used this before and it worked, but maybe it's not the right approach or not entirely the thing you want.

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.5 you can use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh139082.aspx) of `ThreadLocal<T>` class to enable tracking values from all threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  As common with attributes like this one, the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute is recognized by the jitter.  It generates a call into the CLR to obtain a pointer to the thread-local storage for a class.  There are multiple versions of this helper method, the basic one is `JIT_GetSharedGCThreadStaticBase()`.  But it gets more convoluted for a generic class for example, it can have multiple static variables based on the type parameter.  The helper function takes two non-obvious arguments, the module ID and the class ID.  Those IDs depend on the AppDomain in which the code was loaded.

Long story short, you don't stand a chance to make this same call, nor does the helper method even take the thread ID, it is implied by the call context.

You can hang arbitrary data off a thread with `Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot()`.  But note that it is static method and doesn't take a thread ID either, it is again based on the call context.

This is all quite intentional.  A very nice property of thread-local storage is that it is *always* thread-safe.  A backdoor that would permit accessing it from another thread would completely destroy that feature.  Something that should worry you a great deal if you want to do this.  You could, with, say, your own lookup table that's keyed by the ManagedThreadId.