# A list of all active ThreadLocal<T> and [ThreadStatic] references

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection, static, .net-4.0

How can I get a list of all references that are currently held in [`ThreadLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [`ThreadStatic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) storage?

I.e. all objects that cannot be garbage collected because some thread holds a reference to this object in its [thread-local storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Can I use reflection to find those instances, or at least their total size, without knowing their names or types?

Or failing that, some way to show them in Visual Studio 2010?
(I am looking for something besides a full-blown memory profiler)

My motivation is this: I just had a very nasty memory leak where the contents of a [`ConcurrentBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) were held by various ThreadPool threads, even though the original ConcurrentBag had long been gone out of scope and garbage collected. Although I squashed this particular bug, I want to find out if there are more such bugs lurking around.

Ideally, I would like some way to periodically log the number of objects held by thread-local storage, and their size, at runtime.

Comment: You could use CLRMD, a cool Microsoft's nuget package, to dynamically retrieve debugging information from the process in real time: https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/Documentation/TypesAndFields.md
However, with my own testing it seems to always report an empty ThreadStaticFields collection. This may be a to-be-resolved bug. It works fine for ThreadLocal<T> which is a standard type, not a specific attribute like ThreadStatic

Comment: Thread static storage isn't the only rooted storage location.  There are *lots* of other types of storage locations in .NET that are rooted.

Comment: Hugo, I believe there is still no way to do it unless you attach to your process with something debugger-like in which case Simon's suggestion looks good to me. There reason is that as mentioned on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605611/how-to-get-threadstatic-value-of-another-thread this is a deep implementation details of the VM/JIT.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this.

you should instead make sure you clean up using IDisposable implementations and using(some IDisposable) where appropriate.

The framework itself does count references for you but there is no API to expose this information to the running code.